# Unable to run script using crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I am unable to run this simple script via crontab, the script works fine where I run it directly.
I have a similar script for MySQL and this was copied from it, just changed MySQL to apache2. But the original one works but not this one. Running directly it works fine.

```
UP=$(pgrep apache2 | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -eq 0 ];
then
    sudo /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
fi
```

crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * /var/server-scripts/mysqlStatus.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 // Works Perfect
*/2 * * * * /var/server-scripts/apacheStatus.sh > /dev/null 2>$1 // Doesn't work, script runs perfect directly
```

Comment: Add your cronjob to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Done! Cronjob added

Comment: How can you tell it's not working?

Comment: It doesn’t restart apache2. When I stop it manually.

Comment: Dollar signs need escaping in crontab. Why do you have a dollar sign in there anyway? Why don't you have a shebang at the top of your script? You also haven't set the PATH.

Comment: Which user runs that cronjob? Is this root's cronjob or your non-root cronjob?

Comment: @Cyrus it is root’s job

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` in your script when it runs as root? Remove it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Which PATH? Please guide I have no Experience with bash scripting. And these are my first attempts to cronjob.

Comment: @Cyrus I will remove it. But I don’t think that is the issue.

Comment: Show output of `grep 'No MTA installed' /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Okay. I get this message No MTA installed in the logs. Each time cronjob rans.

Comment: Your cronjob produces errors. Replace `/dev/null` in your cronjob with /tmp/error.log and take a look at this log.

Comment: I have removed sudo. Replaced /dev/null with /tmp/error.log and now I see /tmp/error.log. Its empty.

Comment: You forgot one detail. Does it work now?

Comment: No its not working. Which detail?

Comment: The detail was whether it worked or not. That was open after your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028266/unable-to-run-script-using-crontab/61028814?noredirect=1#comment107969736_61028266).

Comment: May i should log the value of UP to a text file, inside the script. May be it result differently when running from a cron? What do you say?

Comment: The cron is failing somewhere, but there is no way to check it. I am stuck at this for like 4 hours.

Comment: output regarding MTA : Apr  4 14:40:01 BenZakai3 CRON[23803]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: Debug your script: write result of `pgrep` to tmpfile, add with the value of `UP`, replace `restart` cpmmand with another `echo`, and look what is working strange.

Comment: @Cyrus Guess what? I removed the part from > in the crontab, now only the command is there. And its working fine.

Comment: This is very strange. But it's nice that it works now.

Comment: Yes. But we are not able to find the issue. I will try to put the output part back after the commad and see if its stop working again. May be a hidden char or space was there. I don’t know the cause

Answer (score 1):

According to the crontab you post, I guess you're using the same user for both scripts ?
But your script doesn't start with a shabang first, and **they must be executable and readable** second.

If you don't or can't make them executable, change your jobs to run your script with the right interpreter...

```
*/2 * * * * sh /var/server-scripts/apacheStatus.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Well, the problem was solved by removing `> /dev/null 2>$1` (is it a typo ?) wich I correct to `> /dev/null 2>&1`

---

Of topic, a better to write the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(pgrep -c apache2) -eq 0 ]
then
    /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
fi
```

Comment: User is same. Which is root. And Shabang is really important? Because other script for mysql runs just fine. Forgive me i am newbie to this.

Comment: If crontab owner is `root` then you really don't need `sudo` in the script :) but when testing as another user, you'll call the script with root. it may sound weird, but i prefer KISS scripts

Comment: My point is that a crontab runs commands. A command is expected, and should be launchable of course. That's why I asked about your scripts permissions ;)
Please, let us know the result of `ls -l /var/server-scripts/mysqlStatus.sh /var/server-scripts/apacheStatus.sh`

Comment: @gildux: shbang is not required.

Comment: @Cyrus it's very good habits to put shabang in your scripts. It lets people (and yourself later) know what's going on. Many people do write and test within their interactive shell (bash, zsh, fish, tcsh, ksh) but can't make it work with cron because this later use a very basic and restricted sh by default.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 996 Apr  4 12:27 /var/server-scripts/apacheStatus.sh
@Cyrus these are the permissions

Comment: @OsamaKhalid: permissions are sufficient.

Comment: well, remove `> /dev/null 2>&1` from the job, so you can have some logs then

Comment: Removed. And tried to send the output to a file. But that is empty.

Comment: also check cron log files.

Comment: ooh, by the way, what's the output of `pgrep apache2` (do you really have two lines?)

Comment: I have 11 outputs. May be process ids

Comment: so your if statement is never ran (it expects exactly zero, not eleven)

Comment: what do you mean? Apache is already running, it might get stopped due to any reason. So if the up variable at some point gives 0 it means no process and it will restart apache. I stop the apache and wait for cron to excute and it does nothing.

Comment: ok, what's the result when your Apache is stoped? 
other thing, are you testing as root?

Comment: Yes. But it worked. When I removed the part from > , only command is there now in crontab and its working fine.